# Linear approximation of log curve

Tags: curve, linear-interpolation

I am trying to **decode a timecode** which is using an **approximated log curve** (see picture).
Its not a real log curve, but consist of **linear curves**.

For example, when the timecode shows 822496, the real time is 2793ms.
I have printed the curve, and found the break-points when a new linear curve begins:

[image: Linear approximation of log]

```
milliseconds => timecode
2793ms => 822496
6844ms => 906195
...
510982ms => 1408395
```

A new linear curve starts about every 83700 timecode-values. Currently I am unsing a real log curve, but I would like to know how to do it with linear curves, to be more precise.

My question is, how can I find the formular to **calculate the real time (ms) from my timecode using linear curves as close as possible**?

The log function to approximate this curve is (fitting at the break-points):

```
y = log x * 119900 - 167700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language? In Java I'd build a NavigableMap (TreeMap) of timecode -> real time, and then lookup the `floorEntry( timecode)` to find the nearest entry.

Of course, you'll need to calculate/ empirically determine the correspondence & build the map; either all beforehand, or growing the extents on-demand.

One thing that's unclear about your question.. can you exactly reverse-engineer the timecode calculation, or is this just an approximation & you are going to search for the exact position from there?

Comment: I am using actionscript. But i suppose it doesn't matter which language. The values are read from 'screen', so not exact values but very close.

Comment: Looks like Google has a TreeMap in ActionScript, or you can just sort an array & write a binary search to do the lookup. See:  https://code.google.com/p/as3-commons/

Comment: I suppose there should be a mathematical solution to use linear curves to approximate a log curve... but what I found yet is very mathematical : )

Comment: Not complicated, it's just proportionality on a straight line!  If T is timecode & R is realtime and you have a linear segment (T0, R0) to (T1, R1), then your `fraction=(Tx - T0) / (T1 - T0)` and `Rx=fraction * (R1 - R0) + R0`.

Comment: Think of it this way: T1-T0 or R1-R0 are the widths in timecode & realtime, T0 and R0 are the starts in timecode & realtime, all you need to calculate is a _fraction from 0 to 1_ scaling your Tx between that T0 and T1. Such a fraction (a **proportion**) is obviously calculated by subtracting the **start**, then dividing by the **width**. Reverse the process to project the fraction onto realtime R.

Comment: I know how to calculate a linear function, but I dont want to hard-code them.. would be the worst case :) Maybe for the first segements, then switch to log. The curve goes on to infinity : )

Comment: No, I was suggesting a programmatic calculation of the linear interpolation once binary search has found the appropriate segment.